# how to call Button Click Event in Another Button Click in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

[image]
this below code is used to get Particular User data from database 
and display in `Readable Textbox's`.
I have another Set of `Textbox's` which is used to `insert data into database` and after inserting data i want to get that data and display in `Readable Textbox` through `txtuser Textbox`.

```
// this jquery code execute when we click on `Get Button`

        $('#btnGet').click(function(){
          var txtuser = $('#txtuser').val();
          $.ajax({
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        url: 'WebForm1.aspx/GetUser',
                        data: JSON.stringify({ username: txtuser}),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        method: 'post',
                        success: function (data) {                                                            $('#txtfirstname').val(data.d.Firstname);
                            $('#txtlastname').val(data.d.Lastname);
                            $('#txtemail').val(data.d.Email);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert('Error');
                        }
        });
    return false;
        });
```

```
 // this jquery code execute when we click on `Submit Button`

            $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
              var txtuser = $('#txtuser').val();
var txtfirstname =  $('#txtfirstname').val();
var txtlastname =  $('#txtlastname').val();
var txtemail =  $('#txtemail').val();
              $.ajax({
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            url: 'WebForm1.aspx/InsertUser',
                            data: JSON.stringify({ username: txtuser, firstname:txtfirstname, lastname : txtlastname, email:txtemail}),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            method: 'post',
                            success: function (data) {                                                            $('#txtfirstname').val(data.d.Firstname);
                                $('#txtlastname').val(data.d.Lastname);
                                $('#txtemail').val(data.d.Email);
                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                alert('Error');
                            }
            });
        return false;
            });
```

how to achieve this any help

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: ok now what problem do you faced ?